# How to deliberately return a page slowly in IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I am running a MVC4 application on IIS 7.5 and under certain circumstances I want to slow down the response times of a page.  The example case is that of user tries to self registration.

On success, with a valid new username and password, I want the page to respond immediately.  On failure, when trying to register with a pre-existing username I want the page to slow down the response to about 15 seconds.

What is the best way to do this within the framework, to defer the HTTP response in a none thread/resource heavy manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most simple solution is to let the current thread sleep for 15 seconds when an error occurs. Your code would look something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: do something to determine if the action is a success or not
        var error = true;

        if (error)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        }

        return this.View();
    }
}
```

edit: or perhaps an async version:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // TODO: do something to determine if the action is a success or not
        var error = true;

        if (error)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        }

        return this.View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are right, that would be simple to code. However, that will tie up my thread and on concurrent usage on a web server is going to be performance intensive as I spin up more threads to compensate for the sleeping threads as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886171/why-thread-sleep-is-so-cpu-intensive . I am looking for something less thread / performance intensive.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5? If you are, you could use aysnc actions. See updated example. This would result in the thread processing the action being returned to IIS when the await starts.