# Why is my cpu usage high and phone getting hot when i'm using a loop in a thread on android?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I'm using an infinite loop in a thread in my android app.

In the loop there is a sleep for 5 seconds.

My phone is getting very hot, which i don't understand because 5 seconds isn't that much.

I also tried to use a handler but that caused the same problem.

Does anyone have suggestions how this can happen?

Comment: You should check with the Debug class in particular the Debug.startmethodTracing() and Debug.stopMethodTracing(), use these in conjunction with MAT and traceview.

Comment: Can you post the code of your thread?

Comment: My guess is that it's not actually the sleep() call that's causing the CPU usage. It may be that because you are tying up that thread for so long, the system needs to spin up new threads to deal with other operations. There is a similar answer that explains this for C# here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886171/why-thread-sleep-is-so-cpu-intensive

Comment: Agreed with fiddler, we can't answer the question without some relevant code (including what the operation when not sleeping is).