# Using dot-trace to analyze high CPU usage application

Tags: performance, .net-core, jetbrains-ide

I have a .NET CORE 3.1 Console application running on a Ubuntu20 x64 server, and randomly experiencing High Cpu(100% for 4 cores) cases.

I'm following [diagnostics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-highcpu?tabs=windows) to start a diag during the peak time for my app like：

```
dotnet-trace collect -p 1039 --providers Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler
```

from the resulted `.nettrace` file opened in Visual Studio, I can see the Funcions list with CPU Time for each single function.

But I understand the CPU time here is actually the `wall time` that just means the time of a function call stayed in a thread stack, and no matter it consumes real CPU caculation resource or not.

The hotest spot my this `.nettrace` now is pointing to these lines of code(pseudo code):

```
while(true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);//<---------hottest spot
    socket.Send(bytes);
}
```

and

```
while(true)
{
    ManualResetEvent.WaitOne();//<---------hottest spot
    httpClient.Post(data);
}
```

Obviously above 2 hottest spot will not consume real CPU resource but just idle waitting, so any way to trace the functions that used the real cpu usage, just like the JetBrains [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) provided:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use external tools like `top`. This could help to identify the process consuming the CPU percentage.

If your profiler identifies `Thread.Sleep()` as hottest spot, chances are that your application is waiting for some external process outside the scope of the profiler.

Comment: the `top` just show the overall CPU usage for a process, while I want to locate to the source code(function) in my application, so I'm not sure how the `top` could help.   `Thread.Sleep()` is used in my code for like a delay between tasks, obviously it's not the cause of CPU high usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest refactoring this code to use async and use 'await Task.Wait(xxx)' instead of doing this on the Thread level.
I'm having this suggestion based on partially similar problem which has been described here
[Why Thread.Sleep() is so CPU intensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886171/why-thread-sleep-is-so-cpu-intensive)

Comment: thanks, but my application is used for local devices control, the concurrent is constant and  limited which rely on devices count (in most case it <=20), so those `thread.sleep(nnn)` lines will not be massively created and destroy, I don't think they really cost CPU resources.